# Unit polkitd.service is masked

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

After a failed Ubuntu version upgrade, a computer started behaving oddly. After initially failing to boot, we managed to make it get to the command line - but it refuses to network (so no `apt`, no LDAP, no NFS...). I could SSH *into* the machine, but no outgoing traffic attempts succeeded. Apparently the upgrade uninstalled `network-manager`, so I tried to get it back by `scp`-ing the required `.deb` files, but... no go. `modemmanager`, `network-manager` fail with

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit polkitd.service is masked. (g-io-error-quark, 36)
```

and `policykit-1` is saying

```
polkitd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
```

So looking at `polkitd`, indeed, it is masked:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled polkitd.service
masked-runtime
```

(a working system shows `static`).

What is happening, and how do I repair my failed node?

**EDIT** in response to comments:

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system
avahi-daemon.service
avahi-daemon.socket
click-system-hooks.service
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
default.target.wants
display-manager.service.wants
gdm.service
getty.target.wants
graphical.target.wants
halt.target.wants
hibernate.target.wants
hybrid-sleep.target.wants
kexec.target.wants
multi-user.target.wants
nfs-client.target
nfs-server.service
ofono.service
osspd.service
plymouth-log.service
plymouth.service
polkitd.service.d
portmap.service
poweroff.target.wants
printer.target.wants
reboot.target.wants
resolvconf.service
shutdown.target.wants
sockets.target.wants
sshd.service
suspend.target.wants
sysinit.target.wants
syslog.service
urfkill.service
```

**EDIT**

```
# ls -al /etc/systemd/system/polkitd.service.d/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 15 10:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Dec 15 10:50 ..
```

I deleted the empty directory in question and rebooted; the service is now `static` as it should be, I managed to install `network-manager`.

However, network was still unreachable, so something else was wrong. I can ping my gateway... so I took a look at `resolv.conf`, and it was a broken link:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May 14  2015 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

So I copied it from another machine; now network works! I also had to install `nfs-common` and `nfs-kernel-server`, because for some reason they had disappeared (and I did not notice) to get my autofs running.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/systemd/system/` ?

Comment: @jjjjoe: Edited in.

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system/polkitd.service.d` doesn't exist on my Ubuntu system. Is yours a directory and is it empty? If yes, does `rmdir /etc/systemd/system/polkitd.service.d` and rebooting help? If no, what's the content of the files in that directory?

Comment: @blubberdiblub: I would not have gotten it without your hint - the bounty is yours if you will submit an answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it was just guesswork on my behalf, so I'd rather pass. I think it would be more helpful for others having the same problem if you could describe what you actually did to solve it and post that as an answer (answering your own questions is perfectly fine).

Comment: @blubberdiblub: I know I can answer my own question (I have quite a big rep score at Stack Overflow, I know how SE works), but the answer to the question as posed ("polkitd is masked") was literally "rmdir & reboot". Guess or not, that was the correct solution that I couldn't find on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forced by the bounty deadline, I repeat blubberdiblub's answer:

> `/etc/systemd/system/polkitd.service.d` doesn't exist on my Ubuntu system. Is yours a directory and is it empty? If yes, does `rmdir /etc/systemd/system/polkitd.service.d` and rebooting help?

Yes, it is - and yes, it does. I did precisely as suggested, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but first check if it is a link to /dev/null

```
ls -l /lib/systemd/system/xxx.service
```

if yes, simply unlink it:

```
sudo unlink /lib/systemd/system/xxx.service
```

Then you need to reload your daemons:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check again the status:

```
sudo systemctl status xxx
```

and finally you can restart it:

```
sudo systemctl restart xxx
```

Be aware that you have lost your service file.